# Why is $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} (2\ln(x) -2x) = \infty$

Tags: limits, logarithms

As solution I had -∞, but my math teacher said that the logarithmic prevails over the linear, which I do not understand. I wanted to ask why this is the case. I thank you for every answer.

Comment: Did your teacher give you any argument/proof for this? Because he is wrong and you are right.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you are correct and your math teacher is wrong

Comment: No, she just said that f(x) = 2ln(x) would "overtake" g(x) = 2x, which made no sense at all. I think I'm gonna go talk to her about that.

Comment: @Atticus: Can you show me a prove that the solution must be -∞ otherwise I'll hear some bs like "I'm the teacher, I studied math in college and not you" or something like that. I thank you for your answers.

Comment: $\ln x < x$, so $\ln x - x < 0$, so the limit couldn't be $\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor out $x$:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} (2\ln x -2x) = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x\cdot\left(2\frac{\ln x}{x} -2\right)$$

Now we have $\ln t < t$ for any positive real $t$, so:

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln x = \ln \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{x}\Rightarrow \ln x < 2\sqrt{x}$$

This means

$$\frac{\ln x}{x} < \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} \to 0,\ \  \text{as x approaches }\infty$$

So

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x} = 0$$

and the required limit is:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x\cdot\left(2\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}  -2\right) = \infty \cdot (2\cdot 0 -2)=-\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\exp(2\ln x-2x)=x^2\exp(-2x)$, which $\to0=\exp-\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ because $x^2\exp(-2x)$ is non-negative for $x\ge0$, with finite integral $\frac{2!}{2^3}=\frac14$.